# PDFs in Sharepoint Online Document Libraries not opening

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

My organization is using SharePoint Online. We have several Document Libraries that contain a variety of file types (Word, Excel, and PDF mostly). Users have been trained to double-click the Title column to open documents, but this isn't working for all file types.

When users double-click on this Title column, the document opens up if it is a Word or Excel document, but PDF files do not open. You can just click-and-click-and-click and nothing happens. The situation is the same with the "Type (icon linked to document)" column.

I know there are ways to get around this (like highlighting the doc and choosing Download), but my users are complaining that some files work and others don't, and this problem seems to have started recently. Just a few days ago, clicking on this column would launch Adobe Reader and open the document.

Has anybody else experienced this? Is there a way to repair it?

All users are on Windows 7 and IE11.
We have also run tests with Chrome and Safari (mac) and get the exact same behavior.

Comment: Update: this problem seems to have magically fixed itself. As of this morning (2/22/2017), double-clicking on the Title column does open PDF documents. We did not change any settings on our site or document libraries.